# How can i deactivate the user form in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have created userform in excel using VBA.
Can any body help me how to deactivate the user form by clicking on excel sheet. and it should activate when user clicks on user form

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean that you want the form to be non-Modal (ie you can still return to the worksheet when the form is shown). To do this, change the "ShowModal" attribute of the form to be False.

Comment: + 1. Or the user can also use `Userform1.Show vbModeless`

Comment: @M_S_SAJJAN If this answers your question, please mark the post as the answer.